# OpenGraph throwing error on valid og meta tags

Tags: facebook, post, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-opengraph

I am receiving this error in our logs which would seem to indicate that we have set an og type to 'website'.

```
Object error: Object code: 3502 message: "(#3502) Object at URL (see link below) has og:type of 'website'. The property 'movie' requires an object of og:type 'video.movie'. "type: "OAuthException"
```

Here are the meta tags on one of our products.  As you can see, the og type is still listed as video.

```
<meta content="217556128271512" property="fb:app_id">
<meta content="17 Again" property="og:title">
<meta content="video.movie" property="og:type">
```

According to [the debugger for this product](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=https%3A%2F%2Fsumuru.milyoni.net%2Fstudios%2F1%2Fproducts%2F57-17-again), the og type correctly displays video.movie:

Any idea what is going on here? Seems this just started up today as I was able to post messages yesterday.

Comment: Your debugger link shows _“Errors That Must Be Fixed: Circular Redirect Path: Circular redirect path detected (see 'Redirect Path' section for details).”_

Answer (score 0):

You can try to check you webserver logs for errors happened at the same time. Inproper html can be returned to Facebook on OpenGraph request which can be considered a 'website'.

Answer (score 0):

From the fb documentaion :

```
<head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb# video: http://ogp.me/ns/video#">
<meta property="fb:app_id"      content="302184056577324" /> 
<meta property="og:type"        content="video.movie" /> 
<meta property="og:url"         content="Put your own URL to the object here" /> 
<meta property="og:title"       content="Sample Movie" /> 
<meta property="og:image"       content="https://s-static.ak.fbcdn.net/images/devsite/attachment_blank.png" /> 
<meta property="video:actor:id" content="Sample Actor: ID" />
```